# AzureAD PowerShell - how to read CountryCode, DistinguishedName, middleName, msExchRecipientDisplayType, msRTCSIP-Line and other attributes

Tags: powershell, office365, active-directory, azure, azure-activedirectory

We are syncing on-prem AD to Azure AD using AzureADConnect and need to verify that the following attributes from on-prem AD are syncing successfully. Can you please help with the PowerShell commands, which can help with fetching these attributes?

- cn
- countryCode
- DisplayNamePrintable
- middleName
- mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid
- msExchImmutableId
- msExchRecipientDisplayType
- msRTCSIP-Line
- msRTCSIP-OptionFlags
- msRTCSIP-UserEnabled

I've already tried to fetch them using `Get-AzureADUser, Get-Mailbox, Get-AzureADUserManager, Get-MsolUser`.

The way these were used were:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName X | fl
Get-Mailbox -UserPrincipalName X | fl
Get-AzureAdUser  -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'x'" | fl
Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId "x" | Select-Object UserPrincipalName
```

As requested, here are some commandlets and the attributes that I was able to find based on them:

[image]

Comment: You find the objects these values are attributes of, and then you use the correct cmdlet for reading that object's attributes to display what you want. Most of these appear to be attributes of the AD user object, not the Exchange object. While you say you've tried using some cmdlets, you don't say HOW you used those.

Comment: @music2myear added more details on that.